# Two very similar functions, one doesn't update state correctly

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks, state, react-context

I have these two functions that are virtually the same, apart from some boolean values and a single `if` statement:

```
  const checkboxSelectAll = (event: any) => {
    const { checked } = event.target;
    let items: number[] = [];

    if (checked) {
      for (let i = 0; i < itemData.length; i++) {
        items = [...items, parseInt(itemData[i].id)];
      }
    }

    setState(
      {
        ...state,
        areAllSelected: checked,
        isChecked: checked,
        selectedItems: items,
      }
    );
  }

const selectAllItems = (event: any) => {
    const { checked } = event.target;
    let items: number[] = [];

     for (let i = 0; i < itemData.length; i++) {
       items = [...items, parseInt(itemData[i].id)];
     }

    setState(
      {
        ...state,
        areAllSelected: true,
        isChecked: true,
        selectedItems: items,
      }
    );
  }
```

After `checkboxSelectAll` fires, the result of `console.log(selectedItems)` is something like `[2348, 2349, 2350, 2351]`. But after firing `selectAll`, the result of `console.log(selectedItems)` is just an empty array `[]`.

I'm very confused. The code looks like it should work the same way. What am I missing?

Comment: Please update your question with a [mcve] demonstrating the problem, ideally a **runnable** one using Stack Snippets (the `[<>]` toolbar button). Stack Snippets support React, including JSX; [here's how to do one](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/338537/).

Comment: How are you involing these both functions?

Comment: I would guess that the event is accidentally getting triggered on both, and `checkboxSelectAll ` runs after, and is setting it back to an empty array.

Comment: You have a magical browser that can run code where `itemData` is never defined.